# Scale lines in wpf grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfExt.ColorLine.TimeLineControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="DynamicGrid">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In code behind:

```
public readonly static DependencyProperty TotalHoursProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TotalHours",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(TimeLineControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure, TotalHoursChangedCallback));


        private static void TotalHoursChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((TimeLineControl)dependencyObject).ChangeTimeLineItems((int)e.NewValue);
        }

        public int TotalHours
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(TotalHoursProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TotalHoursProperty, value); }
        }

        private void ChangeTimeLineItems(int totalHours)
        {
            if (totalHours < 1 || totalHours > 24) throw new InvalidOperationException("TotalHours should be in 1..24 range.");

            DynamicGrid.Children.Clear();

            AddExtremeLine(0, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            for (var index = 1; index < totalHours * 2 - 1; index += 2)
            {
                AddLine(index, 30);
                AddLine(index + 1, 40);
            }
            AddLine(totalHours * 2 - 1, 30);

            AddExtremeLine(totalHours * 2, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
        }

        private void AddExtremeLine(int column, HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment)
        {
            var columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
            var gridLength = new GridLength(0.5, GridUnitType.Star);
            columnDefinition.Width = gridLength;

            DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);

            var line = new Line
            {
                X1 = 0,
                X2 = 0,
                Y1 = 20,
                Y2 = 40,
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                HorizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment
            };
            Grid.SetColumn(line, column);

            DynamicGrid.Children.Add(line);
        }

        private void AddLine(int column, double y2)
        {
            var columnDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();
            var gridLength = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            columnDefinition.Width = gridLength;

            DynamicGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnDefinition);

            var line = new Line
            {
                X1 = 0,
                X2 = 0,
                Y1 = 20,
                Y2 = y2,
                Stroke = Brushes.Black,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            };
            Grid.SetColumn(line, column);

            DynamicGrid.Children.Add(line);
        }
```

So if i use it like:

```
<colorLine:TimeLineControl Height="100" TotalHours="6" />
```

It looks like:

[image]

**So question is:**
How can i change my code, to make my lines scale to fill controls height, but keep existing behavior when width changes (only space between them will scale, but not lines).

Answer (score 1):

If it is only about a control that draws ticks in the shown manner I think I'd do it differently and create a very small custom control. This is all you need and very obvious how it works. You can add dependency properties as you like (like the hours of course). Just by using this way it fills up all given space.

```
public class HourTicks : FrameworkElement
{
    static HourTicks ()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnRender (DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        int hours = 10;
        Pen pen  = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);

        drawingContext.DrawLine (pen, new Point (0, 0), new Point (0, ActualHeight));
        drawingContext.DrawLine (pen, new Point (ActualWidth, 0), new Point (ActualWidth, ActualHeight));

        int numTicks = hours * 2;
        double delta = ActualWidth / numTicks;
        double x = delta;

        for (int i = 0; i <numTicks; i++)
        {
            drawingContext.DrawLine (pen, new Point (x, 0), new Point (x, ActualHeight / 3));
            x += delta;
            drawingContext.DrawLine (pen, new Point (x, 0), new Point (x, ActualHeight / 2));
            x += delta;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the setting of the Y1, Y2's to something based on `RenderSize.Height`. i.e. something like:

```
Y1 = Grid.RenderHeight - 40;
Y2 = Grid.RenderHeight - 20;
```

Obviously the 20 & 40 switch as your now 'measuring' the amount of white space to leave, not the length of the line.

Comment: Seems like at the moment my dependency property assigned and callback event fires, there is no actual height, render size and so on. http://i.imgur.com/FLMcx4z.png